# accessing an ArrayList another class

Tags: java

im just confusing how to access my array list from another frame to another frame
for example:

```
Class Customer
{
    String name ="";
    int age = 0;

}

Class Customerlist
{
    ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
}
```

and i have 3 Frame let say (main frame ,frame 1 and frame 2

in frame 1 i create object from class Customer and Customerlist

```
Customer myCustomerObj = new Customer();
Customerlist myCustomerlistObj = new CustomerList;

myCustomerlistObj.customerlist.add(myCustomerObj);
```

in frame 2 i create again object from class Customer and Customerlist

```
Customer myCustomerObj = new Customer();
Customerlist myCustomerlistObj = new CustomerList;

myCustomerlistObj.customerlist.add(myCustomerObj);
```

now i want to check the size of my arraylist in main Frame

```
Customerlist myCustomerlistObj = new CustomerList;

with -> myCustomerlistObj.customerlist.size();
```

as result the size is 0, but when i check the size in frame 1 and frame 2 i get size 1

this frame 1 and frame 2 are called with button.
im sorry for my bad english

and what is the purpose make a static attribute like

```
static private Custumer cs;
```

Comment: If you want to access a single object from multiple instances, you'll need to create it in a central location or make it static (class level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ArrayList should be `public static`. If you do that you should be able to access your `ArrayList` from another class like this:

```
Customerlist.customerlist.add(new Customer());
int size = Customerlist.customerlist.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you creating new instances from CustomerList class, a new ArrayList object is create on memory.

```
Customerlist myCustomerlistObj = new CustomerList;
```

Every time this code line executes, it creates a new instance of ArrayList. So if you want to access single ArrayList from all frames you should re create your CustomerList class like this.

```
public class CustomerList{
    public static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

After that you can access the list like this.

```
CustomerList.customers.add(new Customer());
```

And also you asked what static keyword is.
static attributes are bind to the class. Not its instance. How many instances you create from that class, static attribute will create a single copy in the memory.